# Getting Error "ExecJS::ProgramError in Subjects#index" in Lynda.com Rails Tutorial

Tags: css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Let me start off by saying I'm sorry if I don't explain my issue as clearly as I could, I'm extremely new to Ruby on Rails and this is the first time I'm actually asking a question here rather than instantly finding the answer here.

I'm going through the Ruby on Rails 4 Essential Training tutorial and was working on the section covering assets where I imported two stylesheets ("admin.css" and "public.css") and then altered the code in the application.css stylesheet to include these two files.

I then created a new layout called admin.html.erb and inserted the following line to reference the new stylesheets:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag('application', :media => 'all') %>
```

But now I get the following error any time I load any page in my app:

[image: Here's the error I keep getting in my rails app.]

I've seen several similar questions asked here but all of their code has another line below mine referencing JavaScript that needs to be fixed.  Often the second line is altered to:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag('default', :media => 'all') %>
```

But that just makes it so that no stylesheet loads.

Here are my files:
admin.html.erb layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple CMS | <%= @page_title || "Admin" %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag('application', :media => 'all') %>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Simple CMS Admin</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <% if !flash[:notice].blank? %>
            <div class="notice">
                <%= flash[:notice] %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
        <div id="content">
            <%= yield %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p id="copywright">&copy; lynda.com / Brian Arpaio</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

application.css stylesheet:

```
/*
* This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which      will include all the files
* listed below.
*
* Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets,  vendor/assets/stylesheets,
* or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
*
* You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
* compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
* defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
* file per style scope.
*
*= require_tree .
*= require public
*= require admin
*= require_self
*/
```

My subjects index.html.erb view:

```
<% @page_title = "Subjects" %>
<div class="subjects index">
  <h2>Subjects</h2>

<%= link_to("Add new subject", {:action => 'new'}, :class => 'action new') %>

<table class="listing" summary="Subject list">
    <tr class="header">
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Visible</th>
        <th>Pages</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= subject.position %></td>
        <td><%= subject.name %></td>
        <td class="center"><%= status_tag(subject.visible) %></td>
        <td class="center"><%= subject.pages.size %></td>
        <td class="actions">
            <%= link_to("Show", {:action => 'show', :id => subject.id}, :class => 'action show') %>
            <%= link_to("Edit", {:action => 'edit', :id => subject.id}, :class => 'action edit') %>
            <%= link_to("Delete", {:action => 'delete', :id => subject.id}, :class => 'action delete') %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

My gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.13', '< 0.5'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read    more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
 # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Sorry if this is too much / too little information.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: have you tried to put gem 'execjs' in GemFile, and bundled it ?

Comment: Looks like that did it, thanks!

Comment: I am on the same tutorial. Adding (gem 'execjs') in the gem file and running bundle install did not resolve the error for me. Any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay! This fixed it for me. This problem occurs mainly in Windows OS. Force your Coffee Script Source version to 1.8.0. Higher versions are not supported properly.

Change or add this to your gem file:

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
```

then update the coffee-script-source bundle

```
bundle update coffee-script-source
```

This should fix the issue.